# How to create video with border in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Want to add border to video like this

i already tried using ffmpeg not working correctly

```
"ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf pad=w:h:x:y:black output.avi"
```

"w" is the width of your border, "h" is the height of your border, and "x" and "y" are the border's origin coordinates.

can anyone suggest the width,height,x and y value please

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want a green border around the video? Can't you add the border using Android UI components?

Comment: use the FFmpeg drawbox filter!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FFmpeg has the [drawbox](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) filter... Just replace the desired width and height here down:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf "drawbox= : x=0 : y=0 : w=100 : h=100 : color=green" output.avi
```

You can find all the options in the filter page (change color, thickness, etc)

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671252/how-to-add-black-borders-to-video/56179969#56179969