# How to add black borders to video

Tags: ffmpeg, console

So I'm using ffmpeg to convert a video to 1920*1080 px, I found two ways to do so, the first one would be to stretch the video to 1920*1080, but then it looks kinda stretched. I used this command for this:

```
./ffmpeg_darwin -i SRC -vf scale=1920:1080,setdar=16:9 DEST
```

The other option is the same without setdar but this just adapts the resolution to the one it started from (1728*1080).

I would like to fill the 192 pixels of the width with a black border. Is there some kind of option to do so? Or is there maybe another command line that could achieve this?

Comment: This is out of SO's scope, which is about writing code. Yet I wonder what you are trying to achieve. All video players I know of allow you to choose between automatically adding bands or stretching to fit when the ratio of the output surface and video stream do not match. Apart from making your video file a bit heavier and annoying people with a narrower resolution (who will have both your black bands and their player-added ones on top/bottom), I don't see the point.

Comment: Thanks for your time ! The point is for people to be able to export a recorded video in 1920*1080 and edit them right after it was downloaded. It seems that if the format isn't exactly 1920*1080 they have to convert it afterwards. So the point is to give them less work after the recorded video was downloaded.

Comment: @spectras I love this off-label use of SO. Has solved so many problems for me and others. Answer upvoted. There's plenty of other areas of SO you could clean up if that's really the intent here

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use

```
-vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1"
```

The scale will ensure that its output fits within 1920x1080. The pad then fills that out.

Comment: Enclose expressions in single quotes.

Comment: searched for a long time for this, works great, thank you

Comment: Just for self-containment: `ffmpeg -i SRC -vf 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1' DEST`

Comment: @rayryeng running this on Windows 10 in command line gives error `No such filter: 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1'`. You must replace quotes with double quotes.

Comment: @izogfif thanks. I had to use single quotes on Mac OS. Pity that you have to use different quotes on different OSes.

Answer (score 14):

**Add border to all side of video with you set your padding that you want**

*here in input one video and add padding=20 all side left,right,top and bottom*

```
"-i",path1,"-filter_complex","[0]pad=w=20+iw:h=20+ih:x=10:y=10:color=red; output
```

**[0]pad=w=20+iw:h=20+ih:x=10:y=10:color=red**

1. Here, w=20+iw means your video width + 20 because you want add border so we need to add padding 20 for 10 right side pad and 10 left side pad
2. and same as in height h=20+ih so +20 to video height for 10 for top pad and 10 for bottom pad
3. x=10:y=10  is use for if x=0,y=0 so border is not show at left and top side and show border at right and bottom side of 20;
4. if we want to add border 20 so width + 40 and height + 40 and x,y = 20
5. color=red is used for border color

[image]

Comment: Really helpfull, thanks! Used it, to place a 1024x1024 picture into a 2048x2048 frame:   
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]pad=w=1024+iw:h=1024+ih:x=512:y=512:color=black" fillout.mp4

Answer (score 2):

Goal: make a 1728x1080 video a 1920x1080 video by filling 192 pixels of width.

Solution: add 96-pixel wide black bars to each side of the video.

Solution, command:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]pad=w=1920:h=ih:x=96:y=0:color=black" output.mp4`

Solution, command, explanation: w=1920 is the output width, h=ih is the output height (unchanged), x=96 and y=0 means the original video will be placed 96 pixels to the right of the top left of the output layout; think of the output layout as a 1920x1080 rectangle which is black due to color=black.

The answer of @Gyan did not work for me, no matter if I used single or double quotes.

The answer of @Sanjay Hadiya did not really address OP's problem. Also, Sanjay Hadiya's answer is poorly written and confusing (but it did kinda help me); I am curious if he is an ESL speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone.  Adapted your answers to a batch file placed in directory with the files I wanted to convert.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

GOTO :EndComment
  For low resolution videos that look worse when the display automatically
  makes them full screen.  This script upscales the video using horizontal 
  and vertical padding (black bars).       
:EndComment

set ffmpegExe="C:\Utilities\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "oldScale=848:480"
set "newScale=1920:1080"


for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
  set str=%%f
  %ffmpegExe% -i "%%f" -vf "scale=%oldScale%:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=%newScale%:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1" "!str:.mp4=_new.mp4!"
  )
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today and while this is an old question I came up with a slightly more generic solution to letterbox (add black borders) without manually specifying the sizes:

```bash
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "pad=width=iw:height=trunc(iw/4)*3:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=black" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Breaking this down a bit:

- `width=iw` the output width is the same as the input width, we're padding on the top and bottom
- `height=trunc(iw/4)*3` the height should be 75% (4/3) of the width, so we get a 4:3 aspect ratio video out
- `x=(ow-iw)/2` and `y=(oh-ih)/2` center the output

To flip this around and take a video (say portrait mode) and add black borders (letterboxing) to the sides just flip `width` and `height` around:

```bash
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "pad=height=ih:width=trunc(ih/3)*4:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=black" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

A common error is that the padding conversion is wrong based on the video ratio, for example if I take a portrait video and try to convert it with the first command ffmpeg will try to add padding on the top but it can't, so the conversion fails:

```
[Parsed_pad_0 @ 0x6000027940b0] Padded dimensions cannot be smaller than input dimensions.
[Parsed_pad_0 @ 0x6000027940b0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

The solution is to use the other command which adds padding on the sides.