# Using FFMPEG, how do we add subtitles in the black bar area or under the video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle

I followed these steps:

1. Added the black bars

   -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1" Source:[How to add black borders to video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671252/how-to-add-black-borders-to-video)
2. Added the subtitles ("burned" it into the video)

   ffmpeg -i "imput.mp4" -lavfi "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='Alignment=0,OutlineColour=&H100000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,Fontsize=18,MarginL=5,MarginV=25'" -crf 1 -c:a copy "output.mp4" Source: [ffmpeg subtitles alignment and position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869367/ffmpeg-subtitles-alignment-and-position)

Now I am stuck as to how to place the subtitles under the video or in the black screen.

Edit: Screenshot added to clarify

[Screenshot of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56JCH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Without a screenshot of the video with black bars we can only guess what will work for you.

The easiest thing to try is the default subtitle positioning in the bottom center.

Here's a combined version of your commands without all the extra junk:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,subtitles=subtitles.srt[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Subtitles will have standard position in the bottom center.

Comment: Thanks. I have also added the screenshot.

Comment: The subtitle text does not get placed under the black bar area.

Answer (score 0):

I get good results burning subtitles beneath movies with a filter like this:

```
-vf "pad=1920:960:0:0:color=black,subtitles=subs.srt:si=0:force_style='Alignment=6,MarginV=246,Fontsize=18'"
```

The above is for subtitles with a maximum of two lines placed beneath a 1920 x 800 source video. You have to adjust the numbers for each case.

The `Alignment=6` causes the subtitles to be centered horizontally and placed vertically according to the top edge of the first line; that is, the first line of a multi-line subtitle appears in the same place as a single-line subtitle. I find that makes more sense when placing subtitles beneath the picture.

I have not yet found documentation I can use to calculate `MarginV`. Experience tells me that increasing it moves the subtitles downward; but only by trial and error have I been able to find the correct number for any particular use. The above usually works for an original height of 800 expanded with a 160-pixel bottom border, which works well for up to two lines with `Fontsize=18`.